# Magento custom module rewrite url problem

Tags: magento-1.9, module, url-rewrite

I created a custom module for news. I need to change url structure for detail page.

My current news detail page url something like this

www.domain.com/news/detail/?id=4

I need following url
www.domain.com/news/detail/id/4/
or
www.domain.com/news/id/4/

Answer (score 0):

In order to  fulfill,your requirement , `need to  implement custom route`.
By **using custom route,your requirement will be fulfilled**.

How to implement custom route see.

- [Inchoo blog](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-router-in-magento/)
- [Atwix blog](http://www.atwix.com/magento/create-custom-router/)
- [Ivan Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4158571)

if you have using Ivan answer then you need to modification `at match() function` basic of your logic & requirment

### Use Core Rewrite:

Also if do not use ***custom route then use magento Core rewrite***

and use [clockworkgeek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4155090) .

> ```
> $rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite');
> $rewrite->setStoreId($store_id)
>         ->setIdPath('news/'.$id)
>         ->setRequestPath('news/detail/id/'.$id)
>         ->setTargetPath('news/detail/index/id/'.$id)
>         ->setIsSystem(true)
>         ->save();
> ```

Here i assume, `details` is `Controller name =DetailsController.php` 
*index* is `an action name` of `DetailsController.php` controller.